# How can I get an array within a request response object in javascript/react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, object

How can I get the 'address' array within of request response object below?

```
{
    "title": "MRS.",
    "name": "Aluno",
    "lastName": "3",
    "birthday": "2019-08-31",
    "address": [
        {
            "addressName": "rua 2",
            "zipCode": "13901264",
            "city": "amparo",
            "state": "sp",
            "country": "brasil"
        },
        {
            "addressName": "rua 2",
            "zipCode": "13901264",
            "city": "amparo",
            "state": "sp",
            "country": "brasil"
        },
    ]
}
```

If I save this object in a state called customer and print *console.log(customer.address)* it works well and I can see the address informations, but I can't use map or forEach methods like customer.address.forEach, I receive an error :(

Comment: the property `address` is an object not an array. Which is why array methods such as forEach won't work on it, `Object.values(customer.address)` will give you an array of values which you can use `forEach` on. Similarly `Object.keys` to get an array of the keys, and `Object.entries` to get an array of `[key, value]` pairs

Comment: I asked wrong, i wanna get the address **object** instead address **array** haha

Comment: Sometimes iterating a well defined object is a code smell.  You could use the properties directly `console.log(customer.address.addressName, customer.address.city)` etc

Comment: Right, look at the question. I fixed it. I wanna get the address array, sorry!!

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you please show more of your code, with the code you have now it should be working. You're most likely trying to access `address` before `customer` has been populated with data

Comment: i'm trying doing something like this, only to access the reservations array informations

https://prntscr.com/vjrula

Comment: address in post question is an example of this, of what I'd really want

Comment: `Object.values(customer.reservations).forEach()` will run _before_ your useEffect and `.then()` callback run, meaning `customer.reservations` is going to be empty/not set.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use methods such as `map, reduce, filter, forEach` only on `Array` **Not on** `Object`.

the key `address` has value as an `object`, To read it you can simply use

```js
console.log(customer.address.addressName) //street x
console.log(customer.address.zipCode) //13901264
```

**If you want to loop through properties**

```js
Object.values(customer.address).forEach((value) => {
  console.log(value);
})

// OR

Object.keys(customer.address).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(customer.address[key]);
})
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the expected response / output ?

Comment: I asked wrong, I wanna get the address object instead address array haha

Comment: Right, look at the question. I fixed it. I wanna get the address array, sorry!!

Answer (score 1):

The property `address` it not an array, if you need to convert it into an array of one element you can use:

```
const valueAsArray = [response.address]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.keys(out.address).map(key => {
    console.log(out.address[key]);
    // etc ...
})
```